# Series solution ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, power-series

I am trying to solve the ODE $y''+y=0$ using a series solution. Here is what I have done so far.

Assume the solution is of the form $y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$. Then the derivatives are $y'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_kx^{k-1}$ and $y''(x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)a_{k}x^{k-2}$

I then combine these into the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty [(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+a_n]x^n = 0$$

Would I then say that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ $(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+a_n=0$ and solve for $a_n$?

My question is:

**If a power series equals zero, do all the terms have to necessarily be zero?**

Comment: @user577215664 fixed!

Comment: Yes you have to find the pattern and a formula for $a_n$

Comment: @user577215664 will this have a specific radius of convergence or will this hold over the entire real line?

Comment: You will end with trig series $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ so the radius is $ \mathbb {R}$

Comment: +1 fr the efforts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+a_n=0$$
$$a_{n+2}=-\dfrac {1}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n$$
Try to calculate the first values
$$a_2=-\dfrac {a_0}{2!},a_4=\dfrac {a_0}{4!},a_6=?$$
And recognize a  certain pattern.
$$a_{2n}=(-1)^n\dfrac {a_0}{(2n)!}$$
Do the same for $n$ odd:
$$a_3=?,a_5=?$$
$$a_{én+1}=?$$
And remember the power series for $\cos x$ and $ \sin x$ functions:
$$ \cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n\frac  {x^{2n}}{(2n)!} $$
$$ \sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n\frac  {x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $$